# What are the answers to Pecan 18?

Tags: typeshift

I'm currently stuck on level 18 of Typeshift's Pecan pack, "Souls on Fire". I've managed to solve clues 6, 8, 10, 11, and 12, but the rest have me stumped.

What are the answers to level 18 of the Pecan pack?

[image: Pecan 18]

(See spoiler for answers I have so far)

> [image: my progress on Pecan 18]

Comment: 5 is Kundera, the author of "The unbearable lightness of being", 7 is Caldera

Comment: Is there any letter hidden under that blue square?

Comment: @pinckerman Blue squares indicate letters that are not used by any unsolved clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Pinkerman's assistance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397155/what-are-the-answers-to-pecan-18?noredirect=1#comment557785_397155), the answers to Pecan 18 (*Souls on Fire*) are as follows:

1. Spiritual centers:

> CHAKRAS

2. They sing where others pray:

> CANTORS

3. Related, maybe in a spiritual way:

> KINDRED

4. Ones that prolong sex are popular:

> TANTRAS

5. Being was unbearably light for him:

> KUNDERA

6. They're often cold and polarizing:

> TUNDRAS

7. Depression after an eruption:

> CALDERA

8. Sparks a fire or relationship:

> TINDERS

9. You can read off them in the dark:

> KINDLES

10. You may read with them in the dark:

> CANDLES

11. Remains that may still be warm:

> CINDERS

12. Like some fish dishes or remains:

> CHARRED

Comment: I figured out #1 too, but I wasn't able to match it with any definition ahah

Comment: @pinckerman Typeshift is a fun time if you're looking for a good word puzzler. Most of the non-DLC levels have guides out there, but this one had me stumped

Comment: I downloaded it while trying to understand the rules :) seems fun!